# hide div after inserting data in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hi would you like to help me. im a php newbie. I want to insert employment information in my database and hide da div where the form placed.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="toggler">
    <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <form name="empform" method="post" action="profile.php" autofocus>
            <input name="employ" type="text" id="employ" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}"
            placeholder="Who is your employer?">
            <input name="position" type="text" id="position" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}"
            placeholder="What is your job description?">
            <input name="empadd" type="text" id="empadd" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9@#$% ]{5,30}"
            placeholder="Where is your work address?">
            <input name="empcont" type="text" id="empcont" pattern="[0-9]{11}" title="11-digit number"
            placeholder="Contact number">
            <input name="btncancel" type="button" class="btncancel" value="Cancel"
            style="width:60px; border-radius:3px; float:right">
            <input name="btndone" type="submit" class="btndone" value="Done" style="width:60px; border-radius:3px; float:right">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['btndone'])) {
    $employ = $_POST['employ'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $empadd = $_POST['empadd'];
    $empcont = $_POST['empcont'];
    $empdate = $_POST['empdate'];
    $empID = $alumniID;
    $obj - > addEmployment($employ, $position, $empadd, $empcont, $empdate, $empID);
}
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        function runEffect() {
            var selectedEffect = "highlight";
            $(".toggler").show(selectedEffect);
        };

        function runDisplay() {
            var selectedDisplay = "highlight";
            $("#empdisplay").show(selectedDisplay);
        };
        $(".btncancel").click(function () {
            $(".toggler").hide();
            return false;
        });
        $(".btndone").click(function () {
            runDisplay();
            $(".toggler").hide();
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And what's the issue here? is the code not working? where are you stuck? are you getting any errors?

Comment: your php code is on the same page html page or in a different php file?

Comment: please show us your ajax function

Comment: i dont have ajax codes. my php code is not working when codes for buttons will hide the div. it does'nt insert anything in my database, it's just hide the div. i have separate file for my database query and    calling the function for my query.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your code?any errors?those will be helpful to understand what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: it doesn't hide the div after inserting data to database.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

**HTML**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="toggler">
    <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <form id="empform" name="empform" method="post" action="profile.php" autofocus>
            <input name="employ" type="text" id="employ" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}"
            placeholder="Who is your employer?">
            <input name="position" type="text" id="position" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}"
            placeholder="What is your job description?">
            <input name="empadd" type="text" id="empadd" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9@#$% ]{5,30}"
            placeholder="Where is your work address?">
            <input name="empcont" type="text" id="empcont" pattern="[0-9]{11}" title="11-digit number"
            placeholder="Contact number">
            <input name="btncancel" type="button" class="btncancel" value="Cancel"
            style="width:60px; border-radius:3px; float:right">
            <input id="submit"name="btndone" type="submit" class="btndone" value="Done" style="width:60px; border-radius:3px; float:right">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$("#form").prev
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
    //alert (dataString);return false;  
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: 'profile.php',
      dataType:"html",
      data: $("#empform").serialize(),
      success: function(msg) {
                alert("Form Submitted: " + msg);
      //alert($('#form').serialize());
       $('div.toggler').hide();
      }  
    }); 

    });
    });
 </script>
</html>
```

**PHP**
profile.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
         $employ = $_POST['employ'];
         $position = $_POST['position'];
         $empadd = $_POST['empadd'];
         $empcont = $_POST['empcont'];
         $empdate = $_POST['empdate'];
        $empID = $alumniID;
        $obj - > addEmployment($employ, $position, $empadd, $empcont, $empdate, $empID);

    }
?>
```

Iam not sure about your fields

echo $empdate = $_POST['empdate'];
            $empID = $alumniID;
they are not in form but works!...

Comment: it does'nt hide the div. what do you mean form name as updated?

Comment: and also it doesn't insert data to my database.

Comment: @user2706335 did you change url??

Comment: Updated means your $_POST['empform'] is something else

Comment: what new code? i just edit my code base from all your post here. and i get errors and div won't hide.

Comment: your latest code never insert my data in my database but it hides the form. :)

Comment: did you change URL???of script to submit form replace profile.php with your PHP script file @user2706335

Comment: what should i put to that url?  Sam

Comment: Url to your PHP script

Comment: i did it and nothing happens

Comment: Please use above code some modifications are made it will surely works otherwise please check your PHP script

Comment: please check and verify @user2706335

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is what I'll do

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "profile.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: $('#form').serialize()
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $('#form').hide();
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Form failed" );
});
```

If you have some doubts with Jquery's Ajax visit [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If you don't understand what jqXHR is, I suggest you visit this link http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/jqxhr-object/

**Execute on click**

---

```
$('#form').submit(function(){

 var request = $.ajax({
   url: "profile.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: $('#form').serialize()

 });

 request.done(function(msg) {
  $('#form').hide();
 });

 request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   alert( "Form failed" );
 });
});
```

Comment: it shows for 1 seconds and hide immediately the form. i change your $('#formId') to $('#form') because that is the id of my form

Comment: Yes of course, I used #formId as an example ;). If it helped you please validate the answer =)

Comment: @user2706335 my code is executed automatically. If you want to do this on click you should attach this to a function. Take a look at the edited version

Comment: it shows the form for .5 miliseconds and hide immediately. i think your code is right but it doesn't hide the form when it will submit data and be query. automatically hides and nver showed

Comment: it doesn't hide at all :( i already edit it and it enters data to my database but it does not hide the form.

Comment: mmmmmm is it showing the alert? Maybe you should echo something after adding to your DB in profile.php so the callback is correctly performed. Moreover, make sure the selectors are OK and you're trying to hide #form instead of #formId or whatever

Comment: it does not show alert or anything. okay this is the real situation of my problem, after I insert to my database, it reloads the page and at the same time hide the div where the form is placed and show another div where the query is show all information that you insert in the form. hope you get my problem and please help me. :(

Comment: In this case, why don't you pass some paremeters in the URL? After refreshing set a variable such as YOUR_URL.php?userCreatedId=#####. After that you could check in your php if this is set isset($_GET['userCreatedId']) and then echo a div, otherwise you would echo the form. Do you follow me?

Comment: okay i'll get it :) so your code will be just like that and i will add parameters in my url, that's it right?

Comment: @user2706335 Yeahp that's it. The idea is to handle the showing/hiding of divs in the php, that way your web loads much faster. Please validate the answer ;)

Comment: hey mr.manuvendev, i edit my code as you said and inserting data to my database works fine but div doesn't hide and when it loads it does not show either the information inserted in form.

Answer (score 0):

You should do an ajax call to save your data and then hide the div, someting like this :

```
$('form[name="empform"]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $('div.toggler').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: You need to prevent default form submit, with `return false` for example.

Comment: Or `e.preventDefault();`